# Difference between Editing Custom Editor and Batch Editing for ASP.NET MVC Kendo Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

Is there any difference between Custom Editor for ASP.NET MVC Kendo Grid and Batch Editing for ASP.NET MVC Kendo Grid ?

As in the demos for grid of "Editing custom editor" there is no save button available in the screen, still it seems the edited data is getting saved.

Please find below the links :
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/editing

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/editing-custom

Also illustrate what is the use of "Editing custom editor"

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The custom editing "inline" example does a save straight after the data is changed. where as the batch editing stores up the changes and expects the user to save them back to the server in one go.

The custom editing example is there to show you that you could have a complex editing type so for example if you had an id field which relates to some text data eg id 1 = "Something A" and id 2 = "Something B" then is could be represented as a combobox, multiselect or a radio button list. Or if this is something that is even more complex then this could be combined together to show you just some summary data in the non-editing version but has a bunch of controls that live underneath it for the editing version.

Although the examples are a great starting point I find them a little too trivial for the editing sides of the grids and something a bit more complex would be really great from the Kendo team.

I hope this answers your question.